# ElementTree parsing in python

Tags: python, parsing, elementtree

I have xml of the form

```
<root>
  <tag1>   </tag1>
  <tag2>   </tag2>
  <tag3>   </tag3>

  <tag1>   </tag1>
  <tag2>   </tag2>
  <tag3>   </tag3>
</root>
```

I need to parse the xml in the order

```
tag1 -> tag2 -> tag3 -> tag1 -> tag2 -> tag3
```

Currently I'm using

```
root = tree.getroot()
for data in root.findall('tag1')
    do_operations(data)
for data in root.findall('tag2')
    do_operations(data)
```

But this approach is giving me and that's obvious

```
tag1 -> tag1 -> tag2 -> tag2 -> tag3 -> tag3
```

which is not what I want.

Can you suggest an optimum method in which i can pasrse the XML in the desired manner. 
tag1 , tag2, tag3 are repeated a lot in the same order as given above.

Comment: What module/library are you using??

Comment: @Schoolboy ElementTree?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, can't you simply loop over `root` itself?

```
>>> for data in root:
...     print data
...     
<Element tag1 at 0x102dea7d0>
<Element tag2 at 0x102dea8c0>
<Element tag3 at 0x102dd6d20>
<Element tag1 at 0x102dea7d0>
<Element tag2 at 0x102dea8c0>
<Element tag3 at 0x102dd6d20>
```

Comment: @Abhishek: those are just the hex versions of the results of `id()`, as a way to distinguish tags with the same name just from the `__repr__`.

Comment: What if I have them repeating 100 times in the XML. I cannot write them in this fashion

Comment: @Abhishek: I don't understand.  I didn't write those, those are the results of `print data`.  Instead of `for data in root.findall('tag1'):`, just use `for data in root:`, is the point.

Comment: Ok got you now. I thought they have to be hardcoded in program. Got your point.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the children instead of using find:

```
for child in root:
    do operations...
```

If you do different operations to different tags, you can use child.tag to determine what to do:

```
for child in root:
    if child.tag == 'tag1':
       do operations
    elif child.tag == 'tag2':
       do other operations
    ...
```

Or you could put the operations in a dict and avoid the if-elif-else incantation.